# Application may be doing too much work on its main thread, when starting an activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, optimization

I am starting the activity from a previous activity but before starting , it freezes for couple seconds sometimes more !

I've tried to disable some functionalities that i was suspecting and cleaning code even optimising parts of it, but none of this worked !

I don't know exactly what part of code should i share here because i cant identify the cause of this problem , still if you need to take a look at it i will include it.

That is how i am starting the other activity using a button :

```
public void startCount (View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CounterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Sorry i am having issues sharing the code on here x_x
SecondActivity.java:

```
https://pastebin.com/SmiJ0Qiv
```

SecondActivity Layout:

```
https://pastebin.com/1Ef27edW
```

Here is my log file :
https://www.pastiebin.com/5d5e7cf1c8e4d

I am suspecting that the cause is coming from this :

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 10298470
```

Much appreciated if you could point out the problem causing this freezing ! Thank you.

Comment: Does it freezes for like 2-3 seconds?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis yes mostly it freezes in that interval

Comment: Does your application get or sends information to a remote api/location?

Comment: am including firebase to my project , not sure if that counts ? and i have setup ads too

Comment: let's put it simply, if you need internet connection to run your application most likely this is what cases the freeze, i will list you some `java` best practices to take into consideration

Comment: might be a huge layout file or some operation that you do on the main thread.... at this point without any code we can just throw darts at random places

Comment: Good guess.... let's make everyone guess what's wrong, eh?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis well i am only on early stages building the app mostly on designing ui phase , so not much work done on the app that requires internet connection yet

Comment: All i did was connecting my application to firebase console and implementing video test ads.

Comment: @Kushan i dont think i am doing too much work on main thread since it only has basic stuff and for the code i will implement it

Comment: @billbylo can u make any changes based on my post and test it?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis i pretty much understood what you have posted but i dont know how to implement it on my project since i have not done anything such as a connection or multiple tasks , if you could elaborate on it would be appreciated

Comment: @billbylo well it pretty much depends on the use case, i will include a link on my post , take a look at it . A quick example: if you have a `String` that you simply concatenate something to it , like, `x = "Something" + somethingelse;` you should use instead of a `String` a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases this is due to the code that launches the other activity in a thread that is not MainThread (UI thread).

So please share the part of the code that launch the other activity and if possible `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`  inside the other activity.

May be your doing time/cpu consuming task there.

Comment: First of all thank you for sharing your code.

After looking at your code it seems that you're doing too much thing on onCreate Method.

You should split in two (at least) or more as you like.

inside : onCreate  just keep code responsible for the view and move the others to onStart for exemple.

Comment: Well you were right there was too much work on onCreate and when i only left the necessary code responsible for the views its running smoothly now , i only need to put the rest of the work on another method and i should be fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In many cases you have to take `java` best practices into consideration as well as using some `design patterns`.

Here I'm going to list you some `basic patterns` and `practices` that you should take into consideration.

You can definitely look it up yourself but i will mention a couple of things here

**Best Practices**

- Use `StringBilder` while concatenating a `String`
- Avoid Regular Expressions
- Use primitives and the stack

**Design Patterns**

Design patterns are **well-proved** solution for solving the specific problem/task.

These are the most common ones:

- Singleton Pattern
- Prototype Pattern
- Factory Pattern

[Here](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/02/05/top-10-easy-performance-optimisations-in-java/) is a link to learn more

**Note:** This won't necessarily solve your problem, but it might make a bit faster the performance.

Comment: Thank you for the useful informations you shared i surely will need to put them to practice , but the main reason for the freezing was the google ads load process and after i moved it to a separate method no more freezing ! Thank you for your valuable time